# How to remove whitespace from a string in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript, trim

In my angular 5 project, with typescript I am using the .trim() function on a string like this, But it is not removing the whitespace and also not giving any error.

```
this.maintabinfo = this.inner_view_data.trim().toLowerCase();
// inner_view_data has this value = "Stone setting"
```

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-4.html This docs clearly say that `.trim()` is part of the typescript.

What is best way to remove whitespace in from a string in typescript?

Comment: try `.toString().trim()`

Comment: this is from typescript's official docs:

`/** Removes the leading and trailing white space and line terminator characters from a string. */`

`trim(): string;`

Answer (score 119, accepted):

## Problem

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp)

## Solution

You can use a Javascript replace method to remove white space like

```
"hello world".replace(/\s/g, "");
```

## Example

```js
var out = "hello world".replace(/\s/g, "");
console.log(out);
```

Comment: It remove all the spaces even between two word, use .trim(), see the detail https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim

Comment: .Trim() is remove white space at the beginning or ending, not all white space.

Comment: This works in **IONIC** too 

Answer (score 16):

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both sides of a string.

To remove all the spaces from the string use `.replace(/\s/g, "")`

```
 this.maintabinfo = this.inner_view_data.replace(/\s/g, "").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Let say the variable has many words in a string 
var str = "           Hello, how are              you?";
How can I remove the space here?

Comment: This is will remove all the spaces, trailing, leading, and also in between.

Answer (score 9):

Trim just  removes the trailing and leading whitespace. Use .replace(/ /g, "") if there are just spaces to be replaced.

```
this.maintabinfo = this.inner_view_data.replace(/ /g, "").toLowerCase();
```